# Notice: Undefined index: in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried debug on my Wordpress. It is showing following error

> Notice: Undefined index: category_one_middle in restaurant-menu-wordpress/plugin-main.php on line 273

```
<input id="category_one_middle" type="text" name="restaurantmenu_options[category_one_middle]" value="<?php echo stripslashes($settings['category_one_middle']); ?>" /><p class="description">Type category one name here.</p>
```

How do I fix this error? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `isset()`.

Try to replace the php code within `value` atribute with the following:

```
<?php echo isset($settings['category_one_middle']) ? stripslashes($settings['category_one_middle']) : ''; ?>
```

Also, keep in mind that any changes you make to the plugin files will be lost on its update.

More info about `isset()` function on [PHP manual](http://php.net/isset).
A nice topic about `Undefined index` notices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index).

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at the plugin-main.php file , I'd start at line 273 as that's what your error said. Somewhere you are having an undefined index.

For instance, if you'd `echo $_POST['someindex']` , and there is no `$_POST['someindex']`, you'd get a undefined error.

someindex can be a counter too , commonly known as $i.